# In repeated upsampleing and downsampling by 2, how do i calculate the output Y(z)?

Tags: downsampling, upsampling

For example, if X(z) -> {downsampled by 2} -> {upsampled by 2} -> Y(z)

Given that: X(z) = 1+z^2+z^12+z^19

How do I compute the value of Y(z)?

Comment: well, you know what down- and upsampling does in time domain, right?

Comment: Yes, i know what it does in time domain. But I am unsure how to calculate it mathematically

Comment: well, you start by literally writing the result down in time domain. then you think about whether your system is LTI, such that you can describe Y() as linear function of X() in z-domain. So, try to write it down in your question, and describe where the problem then arisies, and we can work from there.